# NTP info with timesyncd

Tags: systemd, ntp

Starting with 16.04 it is recommended that `systemd-timesyncd` is used over `nptd` however it appears there is not a suitable replacement for `ntpq -p`.

What is the recommended way to get the server and sync infomation when using `timesyncd`?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1057342/66509 for links to related official guides.